# I suppose this is a familiar number-theoretic operation, but what is it?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, commutative-algebra

Define a function $/\!/ : \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1} \times \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ as follows: given integers $j,k \geq 1$, we have:

$$k/\!/j = \min\{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1} : k \mid jn\}$$

So if $k/j$ is an integer, then $k/\!/ j$ is just $k/j$. But $/\!/$ appears to be a total function on $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$, unlike $/.$ For example:

1. $16/\!/2 = 8$
2. $2/\!/16 = 1$
3. $3/\!/2 = 3$
4. $2/\!/3 = 2$

I suppose $/\!/$ is equal to some familiar binary operation on $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$, but I can't quite pick it. Its neither LCM nor GCD, owing to (1) above. Its certainly not the product, since it extends division.

> **Question.** What is $/\!/$?

I think the operation remains unchanged if, in the definition, we replace $\min$ with "minimum with respect to divisibility"; if so, then $k/\!/j$ makes sense for $k,j$ living in any commutative ring $R$ in which the set $\{n\in R : k \mid jn\}$ has a divisibility-minimum (up to associates.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$k//j=\frac{k}{\text{gcd}(k,j)}$

Comment: Can you offer a proof that this is correct?